# Flash should turn on when double click power button

Tags: android, flash, service, broadcastreceiver

I have an application which has just a toggle button in it. The function of this toggle button is to turn the flash on, when I press it and to turn the flash off, when I press it again. But I want this to happen even when my device is locked or sleeping or working. Whenever I double click the power button the app function should run in services and through broadcast it should turn the flash on. Kindly let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Capture Image

```
package com.example.salal_khan.SecuriteCameraServices;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Created by salal-khan on 12/1/2017.
 */

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;


    Camera camera = null;
    boolean isON = false;

    int number_of_clicks = 0;
    boolean thread_started = false;
    final int DELAY_BETWEEN_CLICKS_IN_MILLISECONDS = 550;
    Context contexts;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        contexts = context;
        ++number_of_clicks;
        final SurfaceView mview = new SurfaceView(context);
        if (camera==null) {
            camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        }
        if (!thread_started) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    thread_started = true;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(DELAY_BETWEEN_CLICKS_IN_MILLISECONDS);
                        if (number_of_clicks == 1) {

                        } else if (number_of_clicks == 2) {

                            if (isON) {

                                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
                                camera.setParameters(parameters);


                                Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                                h.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {

                                        try {
                                            camera.setPreviewDisplay(mview.getHolder());
                                            camera.startPreview();
                                            camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);

                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });


                            } else {


                                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
                                camera.setParameters(parameters);


                                Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                                h.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {

                                        try {

                                            camera.setPreviewDisplay(mview.getHolder());
                                            camera.startPreview();
                                            camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);

                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        number_of_clicks = 0;
                        thread_started = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();


            Log.e("LOB", "onReceive");
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                wasScreenOn = false;
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            wasScreenOn = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            Log.e("LOB", "userpresent");
            Log.e("LOB", "wasScreenOn" + wasScreenOn);
        }
    }


    Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            Uri uriTarget = contexts.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
            OutputStream imageFileOS;

            try {

                imageFileOS = contexts.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
                imageFileOS.write(data);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();

//                Toast.makeText(contexts.getApplicationContext(), "Image saved: " + uriTarget.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    };
}
```

Manifests

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.salal_khan.SecuriteCameraServices">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.example.salal_khan.SecuriteCameraServices.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.salal_khan.SecuriteCameraServices.MyService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score -1):

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.salal_khan.flashlightservices;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Context context = this;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        // if device support camera?
        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
            return;
        }
        startService();
    }


    public void startService() {
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }

    // Method to stop the service
    public void stopService() {
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
package com.example.salal_khan.flashlightservices;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by salal-khan on 12/1/2017.
 */
public class MyService extends Service {


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final IntentFilter filter = new 
        IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
        final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }


}
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
package com.example.salal_khan.flashlightservices;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;

/**
 * Created by salal-khan on 12/1/2017.
 */

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;


    Camera camera;
    boolean isON = false;

    int number_of_clicks = 0;
    boolean thread_started = false;
    final int DELAY_BETWEEN_CLICKS_IN_MILLISECONDS = 550;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        ++number_of_clicks;
        if (!thread_started) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    thread_started = true;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(DELAY_BETWEEN_CLICKS_IN_MILLISECONDS);
                        if (number_of_clicks == 1) {

                        } else if (number_of_clicks == 2) {

                            if (isON) {

                                if (camera == null) {
                                    camera = Camera.open();
                                }

                                Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
                                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                                camera.setParameters(p);
                                camera.stopPreview();
                                isON = false;
                            } else {
                                if (camera == null) {
                                    camera = Camera.open();
                                }
                                Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
                                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                                camera.setParameters(p);
                                camera.startPreview();
                                isON = true;
                            }
                        }
                        number_of_clicks = 0;
                        thread_started = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            Log.e("LOB", "onReceive");
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                wasScreenOn = false;
            }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
            {
                wasScreenOn = true;
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
                Log.e("LOB", "userpresent");
                Log.e("LOB", "wasScreenOn" + wasScreenOn);
            }
    }
}
```

**Manifests**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.salal_khan.flashlightservices">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```